# AOP and Logging

Tags: c#, aop

Is aspect oriented programming really a solution for logging? Consider the following service call:

```
public MyServiceProxy : IMyServiceProxy {

    public IEnumerable<string> GetAllData() {

        try {
            proxy.GetAllData();
        } catch (NotSoCriticalException notCriticalEx) {

        } catch (CriticalException criticalEx) {

        }

    }
```

In this example, I have 3 kinds of ways on how I log my message. The first one is when everything went fine, with log4net something like "logger.Info()", but even if both of the others fail, one might be critical, the other could suggest the user might try it again later, hence not considered critial. In all 3 cases, I have to log, but the advices on how to handle the aspect are totally different. How does AOP could help in such a scenario?

Answer (score 1):

The AOP framework of your choice should let you create pre/post handlers for method calls. Therefore, this is the internal `proxy.GetAllData()` that should be wrapped.

In such wrapping handler, you catch exceptions and rethrow them so that the original code works normally, however the logging code gets the full access to the exception info.

In the other hand, wrapping the `GetAllData` at the class level doesn't make much sense as there is no detailed information passed to the outside of the method.

Comment: I'm currently trying to use Ninject for interception. Because of your comment, I started digging inside the code and discovered the abstract class "SimpleInjector" which indeed allows me to define pre/post handlers. It's strange that only the method "Intercept" is defined on the interface "IInterceptor", but now it makes much more sense. Thank you!